# How to avoid race in File.Exists/File.Delete or Directory.Exists/Directory.Delete

Tags: .net, file-io

```
if (Directory.Exists(dir))
    Directory.Delete(dir, true);
```

The above code checks if the directory exists, if so, deletes it. There's the chance that between the exists check and the delete, that the directory was added or removed.

Aside from calling .Delete and throwing away the exceptions, is there a proper way to prevent this race condition?

edit:

The reason to avoid battling the race condition with exception handling is because [exceptions should not be used for control flow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control)

An ideal solution would be a file system lock of some sorts?

Comment: What type of application do you have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the desired end result is to ensure that the directory `dir` does not exist, regardless of whether it existed or not, then you should call `Directory.Delete`
and catch any exception it may throw, without bothering to check if the directory exists or not. Then you should check if the directory exists to see if you are good to go, or if your operation has failed for some other reason:

```
try {
    Directory.Delete(dir, true);
} catch {
    // Ignore any exceptions
}
if (Directory.Exists(dir)) {
    // The above has failed to delete the directory.
    // This is the situation to which your program probably wants to react.
}
```

Comment: Nice angle on the problem! Focusing on what you want rather than what you do

Answer (score 3):

The best you can do is a mix between `Directory.Exists` and exception handling

```
if (Directory.Exists(dir))
{
    try 
    {
        Directory.Delete(dir, true);
    }
    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
    {
        // do nothing, it means it doesn't exist
    }
}
```

Why not just having a try / catch? Because exceptions are not supposed to be used to handle application flow. You try to avoid the exception with the `if` statement but in the corner case it happens, you handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Is your code the only thing that can delete or add such folder?
If so, why don't you just add the critical section to your code, like a `object` singleton and `lock` constructure?

If you want to avoid deleting an already deleted folder, you can add a process `handle` for it so other processes can't destroy it.

If you want to avoid a situation where this code wouldn't delete needed directory, I can't imagine a good solution for this. Imagine the situation as: your code runs, and after it finishes, somebody re-creates the folder.

Why not just catch the specific exception in this case? It's a natural way in .NET to handle unexpected situations. There are a [lot of situations you can't predict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx):

> **Exceptions**
>
> `IOException`
>   A file with the same name and location specified by path exists.
>   -or-
>   The directory specified by path is read-only, or recursive is false and path is not an empty directory.
>   -or-
>   The directory is the application's current working directory.
>   -or-
>   The directory contains a read-only file.
>   -or-
>   The directory is being used by another process.
>
> `UnauthorizedAccessException`
>   The caller does not have the required permission.
>
> `ArgumentException`
>   path is a zero-length string, contains
>   only white space, or contains one or more invalid characters. You can
>   query for invalid characters by using the `GetInvalidPathChars` method.
>
> `ArgumentNullException`
>   path is null.
>
> `PathTooLongException`
>   The specified path, file name, or both exceed the system-defined maximum
>   length. For example, on Windows-based platforms, paths must be less
>   than `248` characters and file names must be less than `260` characters.
>
> `DirectoryNotFoundException`
>   path does not exist or could not be found.
>   -or-
>   The specified path is invalid (for example, it is on an unmapped drive).

Comment: A lock inside my code wouldn't work because a directory is accessible system wide.

Comment: @JosephLennox Why not to use the exception handling? What are you trying to achieve?